# Git/node getting stuck on old .js -file version

Tags: node.js, git

I'm having a weird problem with git/node getting stuck to use an old version of .js-file.
Every once in a while after saving changes (so far only when the code has some errors in it, often after merge conflicts) the file gets somehow stuck in old version when building the app. Everything looks to be ok, VSCode changes the file and shows it just fine, but when trying to build the app, build process (both develop and production) uses the old fileversion with bugs in it.

This same thing is happening both on Win10 and MacOs.

I have found 2 ways to fix this (both are just workarounds)

1. Rename the file that is causing the problem

   - the old filename cannot be used even after it has been deleted and recreacted
2. <s>Clone the branch with new name</s> Re-clone the repository

Here are example files:

InfoComponents.js (this one had the error in it)

```
import React from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Battery from '@navigil/shared/src/components/SVGs/Battery';
import Box from '@navigil/shared/src/components/Box/Box';
import InfoBadge from './InfoBadge';

const batteryStatus = [80, 50, 15, 5];

const InfoComponents = ({ badges }) => (
  <>
    <Typography variant='h4'>Status / Warnings / Alarms</Typography>
    <Box>
      {badges.map((badge, index) => {
        const { badgeProps, imageProps, imageComponent: Image } = badge;
        return (
          <InfoBadge key={index} {...badgeProps}>
            <Image {...imageProps} />
          </InfoBadge>
        );
      })}
    </Box>
  </>
);

export default InfoComponents;
```

Dashboard.js (this imports InfoComponents)

```
import React from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Battery from '@navigil/shared/src/components/SVGs/Battery';
import Box from '@navigil/shared/src/components/Box/Box';
import Button from '@navigil/shared/src/styledTheme/Components/Button';
import InfoComponents from './InfoComponents';
import { badges } from './testVariables';

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  max-width: 100px;
`;

const NewWatchDashboard = () => (
  <>
    <InfoComponents badges={badges} />
  </>
);

export default NewWatchDashboard;
```

And here is the parse error i'm receiving when build fails:

```
./src/InfoComponents/Dashboard.js
  Line 7:28:  Parse errors in imported module './InfoComponents': Line 14: Unexpected token

  12 |     <Box>
  13 |       {badges.map((badge, index) => ({
> 14 |         <InfoBadge key={index} {...badgeProps}>
     |         ^
  15 |           <Image {...imageProps} />
  16 |         </InfoBadge>;
  17 |       }))} (14:9)  import/namespace
  Line 7:28:  Parse errors in imported module './InfoComponents': Line 14: Unexpected token

  12 |     <Box>
  13 |       {badges.map((badge, index) => ({
> 14 |         <InfoBadge key={index} {...badgeProps}>
     |         ^
  15 |           <Image {...imageProps} />
  16 |         </InfoBadge>;
  17 |       }))} (14:9)  import/default
```

As you can see from above, the code in InfoComponents.js doesn't match the code in error message.

Creating a sandbox for this is kind of hard, because everything works just fine if I'm creating all of this from scratch. So it definetly looks to be a problem with Git.
Any ideas what could cause this and how to prevent it from happening?
Any ideas how to fix this easily when it happens?

-Jukka

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue is with your local Git working tree. 
Give a try with following:

```sh
#Copy the code from `InfoComponents.js` to some other file.
git rm --cached InfoComponents.js
#Commit the change
# add back the file with backed up content
# commit again
```

This might solve the issue.

Or

Try to clean your local `git` work tree:
`git gc --prune=now`

And check if your changes are reflected correctly.

Comment: That cache clearing didn't work on my coworkers Mac. We haven't tried that second suggestion ```git gc --prune=now```. I'll try that next time this happnes. My current problem just solved itself when I did some cut'n'paste/rename operation...

Comment: Better don't wait for next time, just do `git gc` now. Will reduce the possibility of problem for future.

Comment: None of these things seem to work. The only fixes have been renaming the file or recloning the repo.

Comment: Seems that there are 2 options: 1) change filename (and all imports...), 2) push all changes to github, delete local repo, reclone project from github... Nothing else seems to help.

Comment: Ok, it get's weirder. Problem seems to be in on of files that imports objects from the file, but not in all the files. Just one file has the problem. Creating a renamed copy of the import file (eg. InfoComponents2.js) and changing import on the correct file to InfoComponents2.js makes the compiling work. This is definetly not a fix, but more info on problem.

Comment: Might actually be babel related. Adding '.js' to end of file in import statement makes it work again.